# Google colabでローカルランタイムに接続したいのですがうまくできません

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

googleの公式ページの手法に則って、ローカルランタイムに接続しようとしているのですが、うまく接続できません。ローカルランタイムに接続するためのURLを取得する段階まではできるのですが、URLを入れてもローカルランタイムに接続できないです。Pythonでは下のプログラムを実行しています。

https://research.google.com/colaboratory/local-runtimes.html

```
pip install Jupyter
pip install jupyter_http_over_ws

!pip install --upgrade jupyter_http_over_ws>=0.0.7 && \
jupyter serverextension enable --py jupyter_http_over_ws

!jupyter notebook \
  --NotebookApp.allow_origin='https://colab.research.google.com' \
  --port=8888 \
  --NotebookApp.port_retries=0
```

Comment: 「googleの公式ページの手法に則って」とのことですが、解説ページのURLも載せていただけますか？

Comment: たぶん[ここ](https://research.google.com/colaboratory/local-runtimes.html)かと思うけど質問に記したほうがよいでしょう。あと行頭に `!` がついてるのはなぜでしょう？どこでコマンド実行してますか？

Comment: !を付けたのはつけないと、「invalid syntax」とエラーを返されるからです

Comment: どこでコマンド実行してますか？  … ドキュメントには ローカルマシンに Jupyter をインストール後に拡張をインストールする手順が記されています。例えば Linux系マシンであればターミナルエミュレーターなどで操作行うはず。(環境記されていないけど) Windowsならコマンドプロンプトか何かかもしれない

Comment: どこという質問の回答になっているかはわかりませんが、google colabのノートブックです。環境はwindowsです。なぜかはわかりませんがwindowsはタグに追加してたのに消されました。

Answer (score 0):

ドキュメント [Colaboratory ローカル ランタイム](https://research.google.com/colaboratory/local-runtimes.html) に記されている操作の大半は, ローカルマシンに対するものです

- 手順 1: Jupyter をインストールする
- 手順 2: Jupyter 拡張機能 `jupyter_http_over_ws` をインストールして有効にする
- 手順 3: サーバーを起動して認証する

Linux系マシンであればターミナルエミュレーター / ターミナルマルチプレクサー などで操作を
Windowsであれば(たぶん)「コマンドプロンプト」などで操作するはずです

※ 閉じたときなどに サーバーが終了しないように, 何らかの対処が必要

その後 colabからローカルマシンへ接続できるようになるはず